# Laravel eloquent Relationship Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

My database schema is

```
links:
 id      status        user_id       url
  1         1            1            something
  2         1            1            something
  3         1            1            something

links_type:
 id         link_id      links_type
  1            1            external
  2            1            external
  3            1            internal
  4            1            external
  5            2            internal
  6            2            external
  7            2            internal
  8            2            external
```

i want to take data of all links which status is 1 and user_id is 1
and count external and internal links and which external count is >2.

by using laravel 5.2 eloquent.

result should be like this from data given

```
  id     status   user_id     url       external_links     internal_links
   1        1       1       something         3                   1
```

Comment: how `link` and `link_types` are releated? I am is there any fk to relate `link` to `link_types` ?

Comment: yes link_id is a foreign key relate to links

Comment: your answer work perfectly. @nextt1 thankyou

Comment: Check once again I'm not quite sure. Let me know if it works perfectly.

Comment: i just change a little bit your code and it work perfectly.thankyou

Comment: okay. So please edit my code then. I undeleted that.

Comment: i just add condition in link_type model method.->where('link_type',"external");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define this relationship in `Link` Model

```
public function link_type()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\linkType');

}
```

and use this query

```
Link::where('status','=','1')->where('user_id','=','1')->has('link_type','>', '2')->with('link_type')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the right migrations with fk's and Models following code should be working:

`$links = Link::where('status','=','1')->where('user_id','=','1')
    ->whereHas('links_type',function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotIn('external_count', [0,1]);
    })->get();`

Probably should add with('links_type') for eager_loading (N+1 problem):

`$links = Link::with('links_type')->where('status','=','1')->where('user_id','=','1')
   ->whereHas('links_type',function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotIn('external_count', [0,1]);
    })->get();`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work.

before you must create **hasMany** relation for **Link** and name as **type**

```php
$links = Link::where('status', 1)
    ->wherer('user_id', 1)
    ->whereHas('type', function($query) {
        $query->where(
            $query->where('links_type', 'external')->count(), '>', 2
        );
    })
    ->get();
```